# laravel request return message keys translations

Tags: laravel, api, validation, request, translation

I have a Laravel Application and another APP making calls via API to Laravel. These 2 projects are separated.

Laravel and App have their own multilanguage system. They work independently but uses the same key translations.

So my idea was that all Laravel responses must be translations key, like: 'messages.success'.

With this response, the App can translate it.

All of these are working fine.

The problem appeared when I started working with Laravel Requests for validating forms.
In this case, the validation errors are automatically translated so the App receives the response translated with the default language of the Laravel application.

So what can I do?

I thought with 2 ideas but I don't know if they can work.

1: Passing the language into params. Don't know if it can work, how can I set the language before Laravel validates the Request?

2: Override the functionality of Requests to return messages without translate, so instead of "Felicidades" return "messages.success". I really like this approach. But how can I do it for all the rules? Overriding the messages function like this:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'unique' => 'validation.unique'
    ];
}
```

For every rule works... but I feel bad.

Another approaches?

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Comment: Hey, nice question. What's the Laravel version you're using?

Comment: Trying to be on the latest 6.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use this hacky solution in 2 lines of code. Go to `/resources/lang/{code}/validation.php`. You can see that it returns an array of messages by default. Modify it like so:

```
// Replace return in the first line
$ret = [
    /* all the translations go here as normal */
];

// Add this as the last line. This will replace all values with their keys.
return array_combine(array_keys($ret), array_keys($ret));
```

After that you can use validation as per usual and you'll get validation message keys instead of messages. Cheers and hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I wanted. But now what happens if I want to use this translations on Laravel application?

Comment: you'll get the keys. You could do this conversion optionally depending on some condition: if( $is_api ) return array_combine(..); else return $ret;